# Why is the caught error message empty in Flutter on release mode?

Tags: flutter

Below is the code of how I caught the errors:

```dart
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    FlutterError.presentError(details);
    final message = '''
Flutter Error
details: $details
''';
    ErrorReporter.report(
        ErrorReporterInfo(message: message, type: ErrorReporterType.runtime));
  };
```

I will send the message to the server by using the "ErrorReporter.report", but I found the "details" is always empty.

Flutter version: 3.13.6.

Comment: I have solved it, just used the "details.exception" and the "details.stack" instead of the "details".